# Can't use an XDocument in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I'm creating a Windows Phone 7 application that will consume an exposed webservice. For now, I want to load a dummy xml file and parse information from that.

I'm used to using XDocument for things like this, but it seems I can't type in the using namespace in my code.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The XDocument class is in the System.Xml.Linq namespace, with dll of the same name.

Have you added a reference to the System.Xml.Linq.dll?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [How to Use XDocument class in SilverLight Project (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021709/how-to-use-xdocument-class-in-silverlight-project-c)